# Dataframe regexp_extract values from string like array

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

My DataFrame looks like as follows:

```
StudentID          Marks
100                ["20", "25.5", "40.23", "50"]
200                ["30", "20", "25", "40"]
300                ["20", "25", "50", "35"]
```

I need to extract the `marks` within the array and create a new DataFrame. However, am unable to extract beyond the second value in the DF (don't know how to select all marks via the regex `([0-9]+)(?:\.[0-9]+){3}`.

```
df1.select(regexp_extract('StudentID', '(\w+)(,)', 1).alias("C1"), 
             regexp_extract('Marks', '([0-9]+)(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', 0).alias("C2"))
```

Ultimately, need to create a new DataFrame with below format:

```
StudentID  C1    C2    C3     C4
100        20    25.5  40.23  50
200        30    20    25     40
300        20    25    50     35
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the data type of `Marks`? String?

Comment: @ernest_k - Yes, its StringType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string, and, then use `element_at` to pull substrings into separate columns:

```
df1.withColumn("marks_array", split( regexp_replace(col("Marks"), "\\[|\\]|\"", ""), ",")  )
      .withColumn("C1", element_at(col("marks_array"), 1))
      .withColumn("C2", element_at(col("marks_array"), 2))
      .withColumn("C3", element_at(col("marks_array"), 3))
      .withColumn("C4", element_at(col("marks_array"), 4))
      .drop("marks_array", "Marks")
      .show(false)
```

```
+---------+---+-----+------+---+
|StudentID|C1 |C2   |C3    |C4 |
+---------+---+-----+------+---+
|100      |20 | 25.5| 40.23| 50|
|200      |30 | 20  | 25   | 40|
|300      |20 | 25  | 50   | 35|
+---------+---+-----+------+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#from_json) to convert the string column `Marks` to an array of strings. Then get elements of the array to create each column.

However, if you don't know the size of the arrays, you can use [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) function to convert it to a map then explode the map and pivot to get the desired output.

```
transform_expr = """transform(from_json(Marks, 'array<string>'), 
                              (x, i) -> struct(concat('C', i+1), x)
                             )
                 """

df.select(col("*"), explode(map_from_entries(expr(transform_expr)))) \
  .groupBy("StudentID").pivot("key").agg(first("value")) \
  .show()

#+---------+---+----+-----+---+
#|StudentID|C1 |C2  |C3   |C4 |
#+---------+---+----+-----+---+
#|100      |20 |25.5|40.23|50 |
#|200      |30 |20  |25   |40 |
#|300      |20 |25  |50   |35 |
#+---------+---+----+-----+---+
```

Note: `transfrom` and `map_from_entries` functions are only available for Spark 2.4+